# jsf spring security injection issue

Tags: jsf, spring-security

I have the following in LoginBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "loginMgmtBean")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {
.....
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{authenticationManager}")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{rememberMeServices}")
private RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{userDetailsService}")
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
.....
```

in context.xml

```
<bean id="loginBean" name="loginBean" class="com.merc.jsf.springsecurity.LoginBean" scope="prototype">
    <property   name="authenticationManager"    ref="authenticationManager"></property>
    <property   name="rememberMeServices"       ref="rememberMeServices"></property>
    <property   name="userDetailsService"       ref="customjdbcUserService"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="customjdbcUserService" class="com.merc.jsf.springsecurity.CustomJDBCDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource"         ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="enableAuthorities"  value="true"/>
    <property name="usersByUsernameQuery">
        <value>SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENABLED FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ?</value>
    </property>
    <property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery">
        <value>
            select U.USERNAME, UR.ROLE_NAME from USER_ROLES UR, USERS U WHERE U.ID = UR.USER_ID AND U.USERNAME = ?
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

For remember me functionality to work, i am doing the following inside login() method.

```
UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(getUserName());
```

This gives me a NPE. userDetailsService is null. But authenticationManager and rememberMeServices are not null.

my faces-config.xml has the following

```
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>pages/common/login.xhtml</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/pages/common/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{loginMgmtBean.login}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>Secured</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/secure/secured.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: And you're positive the `userDetailsService` was successfully initialized by the spring context?

Comment: No, i am not sure, if sprint initialized it or not. How do i find that out

Comment: You'll see a pretty verbose logging of the spring application context as it starts up and initializes your beans. Any problems encountered during this process will be logged. Always watch your logs during startups.

Comment: in the logs i do see the following

Comment: 775   DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton(217)  - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'customjdbcUserService'
775   DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean(430)  - Creating instance of bean 'customjdbcUserService'
782   DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultListableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(504)  - Eagerly caching bean 'customjdbcUserService' to allow for resolving potential circular references

Comment: But when i click the login button and look at the logs, i see only 4796  DEBUG [http-apr-8020-exec-7] DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean(245)  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'
4796  DEBUG [http-apr-8020-exec-7] DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean(245)  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'rememberMeServices'

Comment: I don't see anything regarding customjdbcUserService

Comment: I am not sure the OP is correct.Cause your created the `LoginBean` in `context.xml`.So, I won't crate a Bean by `@ManagedBean`.It will be ignored.And one more thing I noticed is `userDetailsService` is property name for the instance `customjdbcUserService`.But in your `LoginBean` injection by `@ManagedProperty`  you used `UserDetailsService ` class.Can you please clarify these?I don't think your navigation rule works either.

Comment: Srinivas you are right. I changed name from customjdbcUserService to userDetailsService and it worked. Please specify it as an answer and i will accept it. Thanks